# OpenVZ: share a folder between containers

Tags: openvz

I want to share a directory from an OpenVZ container to another container, how I could do that?

1. do a symlink from /vz/private/109/common-stuff to /vz/private/108/common-stuff ?
2. bind mount /vz/private/109/common-stuff to /vz/root/108/common-stuff ?
3. Share the directory with samba from the container, mount on the host, then bind mount to /vz/root/108/common-stuff ?

Comment: I tried the option #3, but the lag it's too high

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenVZ is great at letting you share directories without the need for Samba or NFS overhead.

To see how it works do a bind mount to root (not private) when the container is running:

```
mount --bind /vz/private/109/common-stuff /vz/root/108/common-stuff
```

To make the share persistent over container reboots:

1. Put **Script A** into /etc/vz/conf/108.mount
2. Run `chmod +x /etc/vz/conf/108.mount`

### Script A

```
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/vz/vz.conf
source ${VE_CONFFILE}
mount -n --bind /vz/private/109/common-stuff /vz/root/108/common-stuff
```

Reference: http://wiki.openvz.org/Bind_mounts

Comment: I wanted to try this, but since I am not a linux guru, I was scared for data corruption. Thanks

Comment: on the container reboot I don't get the automount? strange

Comment: got it, the 108.mount should give a reference to 108.conf

Answer (score 1):

the page give by Aleksandr Levchuk give the following script

```
CTID=777
echo '#!/bin/bash
. /etc/vz/vz.conf
. ${VE_CONFFILE}
SRC=/mnt/disk
DST=/mnt/disk
if [ ! -e ${VE_ROOT}${DST} ]; then mkdir -p ${VE_ROOT}${DST}; fi
mount -n -t simfs ${SRC} ${VE_ROOT}${DST} -o ${SRC}
' > /etc/vz/conf/${CTID}.mount

chmod +x /etc/vz/conf/${CTID}.mount
```

(http://wiki.openvz.org/Bind_mounts)

so it's different from the mount --bind in his solution.
I've tested the above script, and it works perfecly.

from what I've seen, "SIMFS is like a separate drive space set aside for virtual containers. It's set up for machine use, and prevents one containers virtual server from crashing any of the others."

So it should be better for security reason (plus the fact that it's in the official openvz documentation).
However It could be interesting to assess the performance cost of this isolation.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. This is not a forum; answers are meant to only answer the question. If you have a new question you may ask it separately by clicking the Ask Question button.